# Controles dinámicos con JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Resulta que tengo hacer unas modificaciones a unos registros.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var fila='<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>'+

'<td width="100"><input type="text" name="dia[]"></td>';
//añado fila a la tabla

$('.tabla').append(fila);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="agregar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#31aee7ff">
        <strong><font size=4 color="white">
            <table aling="center" border="1" class="tabla">
                <tr bgcolor="#085584ff">
                    <th width="100">Placa</th>
                    <th width="100" class="dia">1</th><th width="100" class="dia">2</th><th width="100" class="dia">3</th><th width="100" class="dia">4</th><th width="100" class="dia">5</th><th width="100" class="dia">6</th><th width="100" class="dia">7</th><th width="100" class="dia">8</th><th width="100" class="dia">9</th><th width="100" class="dia">10</th><th width="100" class="dia">11</th><th width="100" class="dia">12</th><th width="100" class="dia">13</th><th width="100" class="dia">14</th><th width="100" class="dia">15</th><th width="100" class="dia">16</th><th width="100" class="dia">17</th>                </tr>
            </table>
        </strong></font>
```

Los días los generó por medio de php pero como saben los días van a variar y necesito agregar un input en cada fila por cada placa, como pueden observar logró añadir uno, pero cómo hago para que mi script se comporte de manera dinámica y me agregue tanto input como días hayan pasado???

Agradezco mucho la ayuda prestada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes contar la clase `dia` con `each()` asi:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var fila='<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>';

  $(".dia").each(function() {
    fila += '<td width="100"><input type="text" name="dia[]"></td>';
  });
  $('.tabla').append(fila);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="agregar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#31aee7ff">
        <strong><font size=4 color="white">
            <table aling="center" border="1" class="tabla">
                <tr bgcolor="#085584ff">
                    <th width="100">Placa</th>
                    <th width="100" class="dia">1</th><th width="100" class="dia">2</th><th width="100" class="dia">3</th><th width="100" class="dia">4</th><th width="100" class="dia">5</th><th width="100" class="dia">6</th><th width="100" class="dia">7</th><th width="100" class="dia">8</th><th width="100" class="dia">9</th><th width="100" class="dia">10</th><th width="100" class="dia">11</th><th width="100" class="dia">12</th><th width="100" class="dia">13</th><th width="100" class="dia">14</th><th width="100" class="dia">15</th><th width="100" class="dia">16</th><th width="100" class="dia">17</th>                </tr>
            </table>
        </strong></font>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu pronta respuesta es justo lo que necesita y si quiero hacer mas pequeño cada input como lo puedo hacer??

Comment: cambia la propiedad `width` al tamaño que necesites.

Comment: @sebastianvalencia eso ya lo puedes hacer con  CSS, no te recomiendo hacerlo en el mismo HTML.

Comment: Pero es que la cambió y no me toma otro tamaño

Comment: Tienes que cambiar tambien los `th`

Comment: @Clinton Tapia Lagar tienes razón, pero es que esto lo voy a enlazar con una app entonces digamos que estoy empezando a probar, de todas maneras gracias por el consejo